# How to insert CSV file having ',' as the column delimiter, but having ',' in one of the column values too?

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

My CSV file contains a number of columns and long string values. It uses the `,` delimiter as the column separator. But one of columns also contains string values containing `,`.

So at the time of inserting these as 'bulk' insert in respective table, it is considering single column values as two separate column values and inserting it in two different columns. But actually it should only single value column.
Example:

```
"ID","Name","Contact","Address"
"AT00012","Jone Methu",,"Block-20,Muraji peth,Mumbai-40001"
```

In the above sample file, Field Separator in bulk insert, delimiter is `,` So it will divide "Address" field value in 3 different columns and it shouldn't.

Comment: Maybe switch to using e.g. SSIS where the [Flat File Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139941.aspx) supports specifying a text delimiter as well as column and row delimiters. You can then specify that `"` is the text delimiter and it won't look for column and row delimiters within that text.

Comment: But i wanted it to do using script like Power-Shell. Can you help with it ?

Comment: Well, the other obvious way to go is to pre-process the file to use some character other than `,`, and that isn't found anywhere else in your data, and use that as the delimiter instead.

Comment: Well, your CSV is proper. If the importer can't handle it, it's the fault of the importer, not your CSV. So either change the importer or you may be left with using different delimiters or replacing the `,` in the address with some other character. You could then replace it back in the DB if needed. Also, check if there's a string escaping setting, it should be set to `"` (to consider the data inside quotes a single value).

Comment: Your CSV is correct, and Powershell `Import-CSV` will correctly import it as a 3 column table. I think you need to expand your question to include some of the code you think should work but doesn't as I don't think the problem is what you think it is.

Comment: Duncan, I am using bulk Insert option to upload/insert file data in table. But because of this , issue i couldn't. It is inserting 'Address' field column value in three different column. So if possible i can pre-process this file with Powershell and then upload it in table. Please help with it. also see updated csv file data above.

Comment: So you are using `bcp` to import the data? Note that the documentation clearly states "Comma-separated value (CSV) files are not supported by SQL Server bulk-import operations." http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188609.aspx I think you should convert your data into an XML file and import that.

Comment: No I have created SQL Job that actually able to insert data from CSV file in table. But only issue is, single column value got inserted into 2-3 columns because of ',' contain in column value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
#Replace delimiter and save to temp file"
Get-Content org.csv | % { $_ -replace '","', '";"' -replace '",,"', '";;"' } | Set-Content c:\org-temp.csv

$data = Import-Csv c:\org-temp.csv -Delimiter ";"

Remove-Item c:\org-temp.csv -Force

#work work work

#you could later export directly to csv
#$data | export-csv out.csv -Delimiter "," -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Hello Frode..In my csv there is one field in row which doesn't have value and also don't have " " around it. like "value1",,"value3".

Comment: Then just replace those too. it's probably unlikely that your data has ",," inside the text/value. I've updated the answer